# How to associate time (seconds) with a name

Tags: php, getdate

I am trying to get the time (seconds) from the server and then associate this to a student name:

```
    $info = getdate();
    $sec = $info['seconds'];
    $current_sec = $sec;
    echo $current_sec;
    echo " | ";
    if ($current_sec == '1') {echo 'John';}
    else if ($current_sec == '2') {echo 'Mary';}
    else if ($current_sec == '3') {echo 'Bill';}
    ~~~
    else if ($current_sec == '60') {echo 'Bob';}
    echo " | ";
    echo $current_sec;
```

However I seem to get the same result each time no matter when I refresh the page:

**15 | John | 1**

where 15 is the actual seconds.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: You really need to read http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: As others have already pointed out that you *misused* the assignment operator. However you may want to consider using a [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) block in your case.

Comment: @Alvin Wong: ... or arrays

Comment: ...wait **can a second value be `60`?**

Comment: @Alvin Wong: technically - yes :-) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second

Comment: @zerkms I think in PHP the second will just loop back to `59` for one more second.

Comment: @Alvin Wong: it's all about presentation. Different tools would give different results. Not sure if there is an only correct answer of how it would behave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're if statements have a typo:

```
 if ($current_sec = '1')
```

Is always true. Try:

```
 if ($current_sec == '1')
```

Answer (score 3):

Because comparison operator is `==`, not `=`